# Como resolver carregamento de parte da página em atraso

Tags: javascript, css

As páginas de um projeto que tenho estão tendo um comportamento estranho, ao serem chamadas um trecho da página está sendo carregado, aparentemente, atrasado, o código é esse:

```
  <div class="page-banner no-subtitle">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>PRODUTOS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
        <li>Produtos</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bem no início da página tenho isso:

```
<div class="hidden-header"></div>
```

E a ele está associado um `.js`, que é esse:

```
var headerEle = function(){
    var $headerHeight = $('header').height();
    $('.hidden-header').css({ 'height' : $headerHeight  + "px" });
};

$(window).load(function () {
  headerEle();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   headerEle();
});
```

A página fica com um atraso no carregamento, tentei algumas opções e nada surtiram efeito, se retiro ou comento o código `.js` o `page-banner` some.

Um exemplo do comportamento pode ser visto [aqui](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/produtos.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu dei uma olhada no seu código:

- Coloque todo o JavaScript no fim da página, antes da fechamento das *tag*s de `</body>`. Fazendo desse jeito implica que o JavaSccript tem que esperar o DOM carregar completamente para poder, aí sim, executar.
- Eu vi que você tem uma `<div></div>` de pre carregamento da página, aquela que fica rodando um `loader`. Utilize-a da seguinte forma a seu favor:

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $("#loader").hide("slow");
});
```

Fazendo isso, você obriga a `<div></div>` *loader* ficar rodando na tela até o documento todo ser carregado.

Comment: Olá @Eduardo Almeida, obrigado pela dica, fiz o recomendado e o problema ainda persiste.

Comment: Corrija-me se estiver errado, mas algumas partes da página são chamadas por meio de PHP com `require`, `require_once`, `include` ou `include_once`, certo?

Comment: Olá @Eduardo Almeida, o conteúdo .php é chamado por require_once.

Answer (score 1):

A solução do loader é boa, mas dúvido que um JS tão pequeno vá atrasar o carregamento da página.

O ideal é você descobrir primeiro o que está atrasando o carregamento da página, antes de decidir o que fazer para resolver isso.

Usando o Chrome (ou o Firefox) pressione < ctrl >+< shift >+< i >.
Clique na opção "Network" (ou Rede, dependendo da linguagem) e recarrege a sua página.

Você vai poder ver graficamente o que está segurando esse carregamento. Uma vez sabendo isso será mais fácil dar algum sugestão do que pode ser feito para melhorar a performance.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente dica @Rhubenni Telesco, vou começar a fazer isso agora mesmo, mais uma vez agradeço.